# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing in choropleth map that I can sometimes get to load without any data

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I'm attempting to make a choropleth of India and have spent at least five hours trying to make it work. I finally went through plotly's code line by line for the US and I'm running into issues making it offline. Here is my code, errors below:

```
data = [ dict(
        type='choropleth',
        colorscale = scl,
        autocolorscale = False,
        locations = df['State'],
        locationmode='country names',
        z = df['Persons'].astype(float),
        #text = df['text'],
        marker = dict(
            line = dict (
                color = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                width = 2
            ) ),
        colorbar = dict(
            title = "Population")
        ) ]



layout = dict(
        title = 'Population of India',
        geo = dict(
            scope='india',
            )
```

If I leave out 'layout' and put in

```
map = go.Figure(data=data)
py.plot(map)
```

Then I get redirected to a page with an empty world map and absolutely no data on it. If I leave in the 'layout' I get

```
File "<ipython-input-86-ca4c03174fb2>", line 42
    )
     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've tried rewriting the code in another window from scratch, and I still get this parsing bit. It's getting really frustrating and I am new to Python so any help is really appreciated. I looked through similar things about the SyntaxError but couldn't find anything that helped me

Comment: you are missing a parentheses close in your `layout=`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are missing a closing parenthesis in this part:

```
layout = dict(
    title = 'Population of India',
    geo = dict(
        scope='india',
        )
```

The closing part for the first `dict(` seems to be missing. You should try to add it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a closing bracket in the `dict()` call when making your layout variable. Add the closing bracket (`)`) to fix this.

```
layout = dict(title = 'Population of India',
              geo = dict(
                  scope='india'
                  )
              )
```

An EOF error means End Of File: Python has reached the end of your file, while it was still expecting some more code (the bracket). Therefore, it raised the unexpected EOF error.